# Loop through a folder and list files

Tags: shell-script, files, directory, for

I have a folder named 'sample' and it has 3 files in it. I want to write a shell script which will read these files inside the sample folder and post it to an HTTP site using curl.

I have written the following for listing files inside the folder:

```
for dir in sample/*; do
        echo $dir;
        done
```

But it gives me the following output:

```
sample/log

sample/clk

sample/demo
```

It is attaching the parent folder in it. I want the output as follows (without the parent folder name)

```
log

clk

demo
```

How do I do this?

Comment: use 'cd' first. If you need 'curl' it, you still need enter the directory. Also you can use `echo ${dir##*/}` to take off the path.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `basename` to strip the leading path off of the files:

```
for file in sample/*; do
    echo "$(basename "$file")"
done
```

Though why not:

```
( cd sample; ls )
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends what you want to do with the directories.

To simply print the name, without a check whether it is a directory you could use ls:

```
ls -1 sample
```

Better would be find, because you can use filters:

```
find sample -type d -maxdepth 1 -printf '%f\n'
```

If you want to run commands on the files, you should use find and not a for loop:

```
find sample -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec basename {} \;
```

Comment: Yes. Just to clarify. ls sample/* will show sample/log, etc. ls sample will show only log.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your shell supports it you could use parameter expansion

```
for path in sample/*; do
    printf -- '%s\n' "${path##*/}"
done
```

or you could just change to that directory and do the listing there

Comment: The `--` is not needed here.  The first argument is a fixed string with no dashes.

Comment: Also, `${parameter##pattern}` is supported by all POSIX shells.

Answer (score 3):

Because *nix systems allow nearly any character to be part of a filename (including including whitespace, newlines, commas, pipe symbols, etc.), you should never parse the output of the "ls" command in a shell script. It's not reliable. See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Use "find" to create a list of files. If you are using Bash, you can insert the output of "find" into an array. Example below, with the caveat that I used a non-working "curl" command!

```
searchDir="sample/"
oldFiles=()
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' foundFile; do
    oldFiles+=("$foundFile")
done < <(find "$searchDir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 2> /dev/null)

if [[ ${#oldFiles[@]} -ne 0 ]]; then
    for file in "${oldFiles[@]}"; do
        curl -F ‘data=@"$file"’ UPLOAD_ADDRESS
    done
fi
```

Comment: What is the directory here? $'\0' ? I want to pass a directory that's in a variable...

Comment: searchDir is the directory variable. "-d $'\0'" sets the delimiter of the read command to null.

Comment: How do I achieve the same thing in a sh shell? I am using #!/bin/sh